# Ubuntu VM Graphical user interface problem

Tags: screen, gui, virtualization

I was trying to enable GUI on my VM machine, after reboot it shows me blank black screen.
I can not login. Can somebody help me what do I need to do to see login screen?
I have enabled SSH and able to login using remote system.

Answer (score 0):

I installed xfce4 on an ubuntu server vm that i have with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xfce4 slim
```

Then reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Note: it didn't work on the first login attempt, but from that point it worked fine.

Comment: And why `reboot`? A reboot isn't necessary. There are other ways to start a new graphically session.

Comment: why not? even when you can start it with a command, most users feel more confortable if after a reboot all is working, ensuring that every time they start their machine it will work.